# Possible to style button according to if the state value is true or false?

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have two buttons that show two different components when toggling them. For UX reasons (to know which component is showing) I would like to style the buttons according to if the value of the state is true or false (give them an underline and a darker color if the state is true). Is this possible in any way?

This is my GitHub repo: https://github.com/uohman/Portfolio2022

And this is the component where I handle the buttons:

`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Subheading } from 'GlobalStyles';
import { FrontendProjects } from './FrontendProjects'
import { GraphicDesignProjects } from './GraphicDesignProjects';
import 'index.css'

export const FeaturedProjects = () => {
  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState([
    { label: 'Development', value: true },
    { label: 'Graphic design', value: false }
  ]);

  const handleButtonsChange = () => (label) => {
    const newButtonsState = buttons.map((button) => {
      if (button.label === label) {
        return (button = { label: button.label, value: true });
      }
      return {
        label: button.label,
        value: false
      };
    });
    setButtons(newButtonsState);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Subheading><span>Featured projects</span></Subheading>
      <SpecialButton {...{ buttons, setButtons, handleButtonsChange }} />
      {buttons[0].value && <FrontendProjects />}
      {buttons[1].value && <GraphicDesignProjects />}
    </>
  );
};

const SpecialButton = ({ buttons, setButtons, handleButtonsChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className="button-container">

      {buttons.map((button, index) => (

        <button
          key={`${button.label}-${index}`}
          onClick={() => handleButtonsChange({ buttons, setButtons })(button.label)}>
          {button.label.toUpperCase()}
        </button>
      ))}

    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<FeaturedProjects />, rootElement);
```

`

I've given the buttons the pseudo element :focus and that nearly solves my problem, but still as a default the buttons are the same color although it is one of the components that is showing. Thankful for suggestions on how to solve this!

Comment: Set a class depending on the state. Style the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide a style props to any html component.
You should pass an object where attributes are camelcased.

```
<button
  style={{ // double bracket to pass an object
    backgroundColor: yourVariable ? 'red' : undefined // notice css background-color became backgroundColor
  }}
>
  {button.label.toUpperCase()}
</button>
```

You can do the same with classes

```
<button
  className={yourVariable && "yourClass"}
>
  {button.label.toUpperCase()}
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can set styles for `button` based on a condition.**

In this use case, you already have the state `button.value` which can be used as a condition to set inline styles (or classes) for the mapped `button`.

Example:

```
const SpecialButton = ({ buttons, setButtons, handleButtonsChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className="button-container">
      {buttons.map((button, index) => (
        <button
          key={`${button.label}-${index}`}

          //  This property is added
          style={{
            backgroundColor: button.value ? "#aaa" : "#eee",
            textDecoration: button.value ? "underline" : "none",
          }}

          onClick={() =>
            handleButtonsChange({ buttons, setButtons })(button.label)
          }
        >
          {button.label.toUpperCase()}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The buttons are set to become darker when selected in the above example, but you can further customize the styles for the desired result.

[More about inline styles](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/style)

On a side note, it is not necessary to pass state values to the the event by `onClick={() => handleButtonsChange({ buttons, setButtons })(button.label)}`.

The parent component always have these values, so you do not need to pass it down to `SpecialButton` and pass it back.

Hope this will help!

Full example:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Subheading } from "GlobalStyles";
import { FrontendProjects } from "./FrontendProjects";
import { GraphicDesignProjects } from "./GraphicDesignProjects";
import "index.css";

export const FeaturedProjects = () => {
  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState([
    { label: "Development", value: true },
    { label: "Graphic design", value: false },
  ]);

  const handleButtonsChange = (label) => {
    const newButtonsState = buttons.map((button) => {
      if (button.label === label) {
        return (button = { label: button.label, value: true });
      }
      return {
        label: button.label,
        value: false,
      };
    });
    setButtons(newButtonsState);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Subheading>
        <span>Featured projects</span>
      </Subheading>
      <SpecialButton {...{ buttons, handleButtonsChange }} />
      {buttons[0].value && <FrontendProjects />}
      {buttons[1].value && <GraphicDesignProjects />}
    </>
  );
};


const SpecialButton = ({ buttons, handleButtonsChange }) => {
  return (
    <div className="button-container">
      {buttons.map((button, index) => (
        <button
          key={`${button.label}-${index}`}

          //  This property is added
          style={{
            backgroundColor: button.value ? "#aaa" : "#eee",
            textDecoration: button.value ? "underline" : "none",
          }}

          onClick={() =>
            handleButtonsChange(button.label)
          }
        >
          {button.label.toUpperCase()}
        </button>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<FeaturedProjects />, rootElement);
```